# difference between /dev/watchdog and /dev/watchdog[0-9]?

Tags: watchdog

On my (embedded) system I have multiple *watchdog* character devices:

```
# ls -al /dev/watchdog*
crw------- 1 imp  root  10, 130 Apr 26 07:43 /dev/watchdog
crw------- 1 root root 253,   0 Apr 26 07:44 /dev/watchdog0
crw------- 1 root root 253,   1 Apr 26 07:44 /dev/watchdog1

# dmesg | grep -i watchdog
[    2.342104] omap_wdt: OMAP Watchdog Timer Rev 0x01: initial timeout 60 sec
[    6.713125] softdog: Software Watchdog Timer: 0.08 initialized. soft_noboot=0 soft_margin=120 sec soft_panic=0 (nowayout=1)
```

I'm pretty sure that `/dev/watchdog0` is the hardware watchdog and `/dev/watchdog1` is the software watchdog, but why is there also a `/dev/watchdog` ?

***Background:*** The software watchdog is configured with `nowayout` flag, so, once it has been feeded it won't stop anymore until reboot. However, writing to `/dev/watchdog` doesn't seem to trigger the software watchdog and doesn't give me the important `nowayout` feature. I could use `/dev/watchdog1` directly, but then I'd need some **reliable** way to identify the correct software watchdog device filename...

Comment: Good question. I am using the hardware watchdog of the ARM A20, and also have got here a watchdog and watchdog0...

Comment: Stop the watchdog daemon. what does `sudo wd_identify` says?

Comment: I don't have that command on my system.

Comment: It is a part of the watchdog package in Debian.

Comment: You can get the latest watchdog code from here:  https://sourceforge.net/p/watchdog/code/ci/master/tree/  And you can then build that package and have wd_identify to run the command. There is more stuff on this here:  http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/~psc/watchdog/Linux-Watchdog.html  Which might be of some help. So far the watchdog daemon only supports one device to write to, but that is something that could be changed if needed.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question.  According to [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-kernel-api.txt):

> - id: [...] id 0 is special. It has both a   /dev/watchdog0 cdev (dynamic major, minor 0) as well as the old   /dev/watchdog miscdev.
>     The id is set automatically when calling   watchdog_register_device.

In other words, `/dev/watchdog` and `/dev/watchdog0` both point to the same device.  Any additional watchdogs will be numbered greater than `0` and will have only a single device node.